# How to force Vuetify v-combobox to return an array of number instead of an array of strings

Tags: vue.js, combobox, vuetify.js

I use a v-combobox with multiple numerics choices in it.
The v-model is an array of integers but when I had (integer) values, it had strings instead:

```
<template>
<transition name="scale-transition">
 <v-card>
<v-card-title>
    TEST
  </v-card-title>
<v-combobox v-model="ports" 
                        label="Port(s)" 
                        :items="ports" 
                        type="number"
                        multiple 
                        required
                        hint = "Please fill this with ports numbers."/>                  

<v-btn round @click.native.stop="log()" color="primary" dark class="mb-2">Click !</v-btn>
</v-card>
</panel>
</transition>
</template>

<script>

    export default {
       data () {
          return {
               ports: [80]
          }
     },


 methods: {
  log() {
      console.log('Ports=', this.ports)
    }
  }

}   

</script>

 <style>
 </style>
```

The "type=number" prevents correctly the user to enter non numerical values but the v-model variable (ports) is filled with strings for each new value.

When I had 345 and 56 to the v-combobox, the log method then shows:

```
Ports= [80, "345", "56"]
```

with strings for added values, instead of:

```
Ports=[80,345,56]
```

with only numbers, as I would prefer !

Do you know a way to force the result array to contain only numbers ?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: `v-model` and `items` bind to same `ports` object?

Comment: I currently have the same issue. I wonder if you ever figured out how to get this to work?  The issue isn't really about validation it's about the value type that gets stored in the `v-model`.

Answer (score 1):

I've made custom validation function, based on [combobox rules property](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/combobox#api), which enables form validation, therefore I haven't used parameter type=number:

```
<v-form ref="form" v-model="valid" lazy-validation>
  <v-layout wrap>
    <v-flex xs12>
      <v-combobox 
        v-model="phones"
        :rules="intRule"
        deletable-chips 
        :items="phones" 
        hide-selected
        label="Phones"
        multiple
        persistent-hint
        small-chips>
      </v-combobox>
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
 </v-form>
<script>
export default {
data: () => ({
phones:[],
valid: false,
intRule: [function(v){
  for (var i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
  if(/[^0-9]/g.test(v[i])){
      return "Insert numbers only";
    }
    v[i] = parseInt(v[i]);
  }
  return true;
  }]})
}
</script>
```